# SQLite image malformed after accessing the DB for the second time

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

### TL;DR

I create my DB with SQLite using python. But when I try to use the DB, I can access it only once. If I try to access it a second time, I receive the error `image is malformed`.

**Why can't I use my database several times ?** I double check if I were closing the DB correctly. I don't understand what's going on.

---

I create my DB with this script :

```
import sqlite3

DATABASE_LOCATION = 'Data/database.db'

# exec(open("Scripts/create_db.py").read())

with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_LOCATION) as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE 'members'(
            'discord_id' TEXT NOT NULL, 
            'reputation' INTEGER NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY('discord_id')
            );
    """)

    cursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE 'mission'(
            'mission_id' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, 
            'description' TEXT NOT NULL,
            'price' INTEGER NOT NULL,
            'giver' TEXT NOT NULL,
            'receiver' TEXT NOT NULL,
            'complete' INTEGER NOT NULL,
            'create_date' TEXT NOT NULL,
            'complete_date' TEXT,
            FOREIGN KEY('giver') REFERENCES members('discord_id'),
            FOREIGN KEY('receiver') REFERENCES members('discord_id')
            );
    """)

    db.commit()
```

And then I use this script for test :

```
import sqlite3

DATABASE_LOCATION = 'Data/database.db'


db = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_LOCATION)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO members(discord_id, reputation) VALUES(?,?)''', ('1', 1))
db.commit()
db.close()

db = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_LOCATION)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO members(discord_id, reputation) VALUES(?,?)''', ('2', 2))
db.commit()
db.close()

db = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_LOCATION)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO members(discord_id, reputation) VALUES(?,?)''', ('3', 3))
db.commit()
db.close()

db = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_LOCATION)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''SELECT discord_id, reputation FROM members WHERE       
discord_id=?''', ('2',))
info = cursor.fetchone()
db.close()

print(info)
```

I run the creation script : everything is fine. I then run the test script a first time : everything is fine, `('2', 2)` is displayed in the console.

I then run the test script a second time, and I receive this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

---

### EDIT

I fixed the problem of Uniqueness (thanks for pointing this out).

Maybe it's because I'm running this on a Repl.it.

I put this example here : https://repl.it/@NicolasRemond/SociableFluidOrigin
So you can access it and try it. Just delete the database file, run the creation file with `exec(open("create.py").read())` in the console and then the other script `exec(open("test.py").read())`

Comment: I cannot understand how `DATABASE_LOCATION` magically got right values in your test script

Comment: Running your second program twice gives me `sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: members.discord_id` as expected.

Comment: Good point ! I forgot it. I honnestly have no idea how it worked before, without it. But I added it and I still have the same problem...